# Android SET resource file items

Tags: java, android, android-resources

In android, **getResource()** method is available to get resources declared in xml files. Like:

```
<resources>
<string name="sample_1">Sample 1</string>
<string name="sample_2">Sample 2</string>
<string name="sample_3">Sample 3</string>
<string name="sample_4">Sample 4</string>
<string name="sample_5">Sample 5</string>
</resources>
```

and i want **sample_1** text in class i do it like:

```
getString(R.string.sample_1);
```

So get method is there to access them but where is set method. I searched a lot on internet but not find anything useful. What is the way to set string and color resources at run time via **java**. Internet is full of example like this:

```
TextView ab = findviewbyid(........);
ab.setText("bla bla");
```

i dont want this, i want resource file item directly change like:

```
setResouces(R.color.primarycolor) to #00000
```

is there a solution like above?

Comment: There is no **set** method, because resources **can't be written**. You can use other methods, like saving your vaules into SharedPReferences or databases. Or other text or xml files on your storage.

Comment: I think there is no set method and there is no need for that. why do you need that? describe your use case, and probably there is another solution for your problem.

Comment: Sorry. Not possible.

Comment: is there no way to update resources value?

Comment: basically my app uses lots of colors and colors are fetched online, for now i am instantiating every object to set color. If there is a way to update resource file directly it will be helpful, and reduces code.

Comment: `is there no way to update resources value?` As I already told you: **NO**.

Comment: As I remember Activity.getResources method isn't "final". You can try to implement resources wrapper class (based on MockResources) and return it from overridden getResources() method of you Activity. Your wrapper should return you custom value or value from resources if custom value is not set. No samples - just idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setResources method I think. You can get the String resource in the following way dynamically

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.sample_1));


TextView ab = findviewbyid(........);
```

//To set the value in string.xml

```
ab.setText("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no such method to set resources but you can create resources at runtime using your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        def var = "";
        debug {
            var = "debug"
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_DATE", "\"12345\""
            resValue "string", "buildTime", "12345678"
            }
}
```

Adding similar code to your build.gradle will create a string resource when you build you application.

Comment: explain this little more

Comment: This is one way of creating a resource using your gradle at the time of building your app. It will create string resource with name "buildTime" which will have the value "12345678". After you build your app